# How to pass a class reference to a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, function, generics, nested, type-parameter

I want to pass the reference of the same class to the GetInquiry class dynamically that I would to MyClass.

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: class
{
    public T Inquiry(T obj)
    {
         string Username = "myUser";

         Task<MyClass<T>> myTask = GetInquiry<MyClass<T>>.Inquire(Username); //Want to pass the same class reference passed in MyClass<T>
         obj = myTask.Result; //gives error of implicit conversion
         return obj;
    }
}
```

```
public static class GetInquiry<T> where T: class
{
    public static async Task<T> Inquire(string Username)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

So, when I pass any class to MyClass, its reference should also be passed to down to the GetInquiry class at runtime, but I end up getting error instead that it cannot implicitly convert the types.
Workarounds are also appreciated.

Comment: Assuming `Inquiry<T>` is supposed to be `GetInquiry<T>` and the `GetInquiry` method is actually called `Inquire`, your code seems to be already achieving that dynamically. What is the problem?

Comment: @Sweeper The code has been edited. Please review.

Comment: @OddCommand24 I read your question 3 times and I’m still not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. Could you please update the question to display what you have currently, what the error is that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `public T Inquiry(T obj)` method is trying to return `T`, but in the code you are not assigning `T` to `obj` you are trying to assign `MyClass<T>` to `obj`

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: class
{
    public T Inquiry(T obj)
    {
        string Username = "myUser";

         Task<MyClass<T>> myTask = GetInquiry<MyClass<T>>.Inquire(Username);
         obj = myTask.Result; // (Result here is MyClass<T> and not T, so you can't assign it to T obj)
         return obj;
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case this can be solved in a lot of different ways, you can change the `GetInquiry<MyClass<T>>.Inquire(Username)` to `GetInquiry<T>.Inquiry(Username)`, you can change the `MyClass<T>.Inquiry()` return type from `T` to `MyClass<T>`.

What the right approach is depends entirily on your usecase and design.